# Template functor wrapper that can return a void or non-void value

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

How to return an arbitrary type (either void or non-void) from a template functor wrapper? I use the wrapper for pre- and post- conditions, so I need to store the returned value in a local variable before returning it from wrapper. But when the returned type is void the compiler gives and error, because variables can't have a void type. What can be done here?

```
template <typename Functor, typename... Args>
auto Decorate(Functor f, Args&&... args)
-> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
    // preconditions
    const auto result = f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // postconditions
    return result;
}
```

Comment: what are the pre/post conditions for void?

Comment: I can think of two quick solutions: 1) put the pre and post conditions as ctor and dtor of a separate class and then `return f(...)` (you are allowed to return void from templates as an exception to the rules), or 2) make an overload for void-returning callables, but that means duplicated code.

Comment: I use this to measure the execution time of a function.

Answer (score 5):

Run your pre- and post-conditions in the constructor/destructor of a suitable class and return the value directly! As long as you don't need to touch the return value in your post-condition that shouldn't be a problem!

```
struct condition
{
    condition() { /* do pre-condition checks */ }
    ~condition() { /* do post-condition checks */ }
    condition(condition&) = delete;
    void operator= (condition&) = delete;
};
template <typename Functor, typename... Args>
auto Decorate(Functor f, Args&&... args)
    -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
    condition checker;
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sfinae:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Functor, typename... Args>
auto Decorate(Functor f, Args&&... args)
    -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)), void>::value, void>::type
{
    // preconditions
    f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // postconditions
    return;
}

template <typename Functor, typename... Args>
auto Decorate(Functor f, Args&&... args)
    -> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)), void>::value, decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))>::type
{
    // preconditions
    auto result = f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // postconditions
    return result;
}
```

test:

```
void f(int x) {
    std::cout << "f(" << x << ")" << std::endl;
    return;
}

int g(int x) {
    std::cout << "g(" << x << ")" << std::endl;
    return x * x;
}

int main()
{       
    Decorate(f, 3);
    std::cout << Decorate(g, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

> f(3)
>   g(3)
>   9

Comment: You can replace `decltype(...)` with `typename std::result_of<Functor>::type`

Comment: @0x499602D2 I guess you meant `typename std::result_of<Functor(Args...)>::type`

Comment: @0x499602D2 - I've just run into a problem using the construct :-) Thank your for the comment.